# Session Timeout Popup - How to put javascript in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session

i want to make comfirmation popup (yes/no button) in php if session already limit. If the user click yes button in popup it stay in the website or refresh session, if click no, session terminated. How can i do this?.. below is my php code :

```
  if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY1']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY1'] > 7200)) {

        if (isset($_SESSION['member_id'])) {

***<script>comfirmation popup code in here</script>***

            session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time
            session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage


            header('Location: '.AT_BASE_HREF.'login.php?loginexpired=true');
            exit;
        }
        //echo "awa";
    } else {
        //echo "aba" . $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY1'];
    }
```

my problems i cannot put javascript code inside the php. how to put javascript of jquery inside php?

this is my code i want :

```
         <script type='text/javascript'>

var answer = confirm ("Are you having fun?")
if (answer)
alert ("Woo Hoo! So am I.")
else
alert ("Darn. Well, keep trying then.")

  session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time
  session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
    //header('Location: '.AT_BASE_HREF.'login.php?loginexpired=true');
     window.location.href="<?php AT_BASE_HREF.'login.php?loginexpired=true'; ?>"; 

// -->

         </script>
```

Comment: Show us your script you want to inject.

Comment: put the functionality into a seperate file and reference that in a `<script>` tag, most of the time you shouldn't directly inject js into a server-side rendered page

Comment: @Fred-ii- i added the script i want

Comment: @konkked do i need to used imclude_once funtion?

Comment: if you want to add it into every portion of your script would think you would just write the tag in the head section, or use a master page, not a phper so not 100% sure how to, but the script tag in your html rendering portion, just use `<script src="/path/to/file.js"></script>`, put the javascript in the file that path maps to on your server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code

```
       if (isset($_SESSION['member_id'])) {
?>
         <script type='text/javascript'>

           alert('test');

         </script>
<?php
        session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time
        session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage



 ?>
           <script type='text/javascript'>
              location.href="<?php echo AT_BASE_HREF.'login.php?loginexpired=true'?>";
           </script>

  <?php          
  }
```

It must be work. First check alert box.

Comment: my problem is there is error regarding < in the php.. do i need to echo <script> ?

Comment: before add script tag you have to close php ?> tag
then after script open again php tag <?php

Comment: remove your  header('Location: '.AT_BASE_HREF.'login.php?loginexpired=true'); exit;
then it prompt javascript alert. 
Then use javascript location.href="<?php AT_BASE_HREF.'login.php?loginexpired=true'; ?>";

Comment: wow.. it works like charm.. how to put this in javascript? header('Location: '.AT_BASE_HREF.'login.php?loginexpired=true');

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67826/discussion-between-airi-and-sameeraa4ever).